# Can I use THREE js ExtrudeGeometry to extrude a shape over a sharp path?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have used CatmullRomCurve3 to extrude over a curved line. Is it possible to extrude over a sharp line like below:

[image]

What I want to have is:

[image]

With possibly as few polygons as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating vertices, faces and calculating UVs myself. For anyone wanting to do something similar [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1741) helped me a lot. I still do not know if ExtrudeGeometry could have been used here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could create a geometry of steps, but to do so using ExtrudeGeometry, you could do something like:

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo( 0, 0 );
var numSteps = 10, stepSize = 10;

for ( var i = 0; i < numSteps; i ++ ) {

    shape.lineTo( i * stepSize, ( i + 1 ) * stepSize );
    shape.lineTo( ( i + 1 ) * stepSize, ( i + 1 ) * stepSize );

}

var extrudeSettings = { amount: 100, bevelEnabled: false };
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffffff } );
var steps = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

For a full example based on webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes2, see below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cc146hcx/

Comment: Thank you, this is not quite what I was after. You are not extruding by following some line here. I am going to edit my question to make it clearer.